# Not getting unique values inspite of using the distinct function

Tags: sql, presto

I am using the below code to return a set of distinct UUIDs and a corresponding date when the first action was taken on those UUIDs. The raw data will have non-distinct UUIDs and a corresponding date when an action was taken. I am trying to extract unique UUIDs and the first date when the action was taken as represented by date1. Can someone help where I am going wrong.

The output that I get is the same raw data and the UUIDs are unfortunately non-unique and has many duplicates

```
with raw_data as (
select UUID, cast(datestring as timestamp) as date1
from raw)

select
distinct UUID,
date_trunc('week', date1)
from raw_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `min()` aggregation function:

```
select UUID,
       min(date_trunc('week', cast(datestring as timestamp))) 
from raw
group by UUID;
```

This should do everything your query is doing.  There is no need for a subquery or CTE.

Comment: Thanks. Should I do that in the subquery? Or should it be in the main query? I tried doing the main function in the main query. I used the code distinct uuid,
    min(date_trunc('week',cast(datestromg as timestamp))) but the output gives me unique UUIDs but i only get one ouput in the second column. Ideally there should be atleast 3-4 timestamps which is what I was expecting